# CSS: How do I shrink a div to beyond a font's invisible padding?

Tags: css

code: http://jsfiddle.net/xVCrn/1/
(works best in chrome / webkit)

I'm trying to get the red part to have 1px of margin inside the dark buttony area. but I can't seem to change the height of the red part. =(

the goal: [image]

Comment: This makes me sad: `(works best in chrome / webkit)` :(

Comment: haven't added the other browser specific gradients, just trying to get the initial design right., other browsers later. =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `display-inline` you can set it's height. You will also want to set the `line-height` as well. For example I added `line-height:17px;` and it centered it pretty good.

Example: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/brenjt/xVCrn/3/)

Tip: For webkit browsers on elements with a `border` of 1px and `border-radius`. Use `1px double #color` It'll help with the jagged lines. I believe this is mostly a problem in Chrome that hasn't been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to the red part lets you control its height.

Here's an example (with some padding added to make it look nice): http://jsfiddle.net/xVCrn/

Comment: is there a way to move the text up so it's centered?

Comment: actually, is there a way I can make it look like (updated question)